# Loading an asset stored within a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I have a JSON file stored within my extension called settings.json.  I can get the URL of the file using:

```
chrome.extension.getURL("settings.json");
```

But now that I have the URL, how do I actually load the contents of that file so I can JSON.parse it and use it?  The reason I'm doing this is that there is a server component, and I want to make deployment and testing on multiple servers easier (dev, staging, production, etc.)  Alternatively if there's a way to add custom attributes to the manifest.json and access them, that would also work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you make your setting.js look like:

```
var settings =  {"param":value,...};
```

Then you can just include it on a background page and use settings variable:

```
<script src="settings.js"></script>
```

If you want to have pure json in your file without assigning it to any variables then you can load it using XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), true);
xhr.send();
```

or if you included jquery into your project:

```
$.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), function(settings) {
  //..
});
```

(btw using `chrome.extension.getURL` is required only if you are accessing a file from a content script, otherwise you can just use relative path `/config_resources/config.json`)

Comment: I may end up doing your first suggestion.  With the second, I get the following error (from within a content script): XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome-extension://<APPID>/settings.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Comment: @Evan Ok then I was wrong about content script, sorry. If you need it in a content script you can send a request to background page using `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and ask it to get settings for you (you will need to send a request in any case, even with first method).

Comment: *otherwise you can just use relative path* - unless it would be a CORB request, which it would probably be, as Chrome extensions work alongside any website.

Comment: Unfortunately, not allowed any more: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Answer (score 2):

I can verify that requesting the resource from an XHR in the background page works as previously described.  Just be sure to add 'self' to the `connect-src` portion of your `content_security_policy`.

Comment: Another point should be also considered: web_accessible_resources https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236129/742884