# How can I package JSON files with my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I have created an extension containing a pre-existing javascript file. This javascript file requires a json config file in the same directory, but putting that file in the same directory in the extension folder didn't work. Is there some special way I have to do this?

This problem also proved IMPOSSIBLE to Google since all extensions needs a json manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it in the `content_scripts` section of the `manifest.json`.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["extension.js", "config.json"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720258/loading-an-asset-stored-within-a-chrome-extension. Looks like it might do the trick for you.