# Get local file inside the extension folder in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that I can't get a local file from within the extension directory. It is possible to get a file that is *inside* the extension directory itself?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL) to get a fully-qualified URL to a resource.

```js
// Outputs path to the file regardless if it exits
> chrome.runtime.getURL('assets/extension-icon.png');
"chrome-extension://kfcphocilcidmjolfgicbchdfjjlfkmh/assets/extension-icon.png"
```

The *`chrome-extension`* protocol plus the extension id, will be the address for the extension's root directory.

If you need something more powerful, you might also use HTML5's [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) which can create, read, write and list files from a sandbox in the current user's local file system.

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL` is deprecated since Chrome 58. Use `chrome.runtime.getURL`.

Answer (score 13):

On Chrome 17 or later, for this to work you must include the **web_accessible_resources** section to allow an image packed within the extension to be injected into a web page. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

```
{...
"web_accessible_resources": [
"images/my-awesome-image1.png",
"images/my-amazing-icon1.png"
],...}
```

(courtesy of jhaury)

Comment: I've done this but I still can't load my file via the `chrome-extension://...` format. It's a JSON file, it always 404s. Any ideas?