# accessing extension stylesheets via extension javascript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome content script extension that includes a css file (mystyle.css) which is bundled into the extenstion CRX. As far as I can tell, there are two ways to inject this this stylesheet into the content of a page.

No matter which way the stylesheet is injected into the page, I cannot access the CSS rules associated with that stylesheet.

Injection method #1:

```
// From a script running in the context of background.html:
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: 'mystyle.css'});
```

Injection method #2:

```
// From a script running in the context of the content, already
// injected by the background page via chrome.tabs.executeScript.
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href",
    chrome.extension.getURL('mystyle.css'));
```

From JavaScript running in the context of the content, injected by the background page, I cannot see the stylesheet in the list of those listed in document.styleSheets, when it is injected using method #1.  When injected using method #2, it is listed with a chrome-extension:// href, but the cssRules property of that the sheet is always null.

I would expect this for CSS sheets that are linked to the document from other domains, but my script should have access to chrome-extension:// URIs that pertain to my extension.

The avenue that I'm currently investigating is raw string access to the resource contents of the CSS file that I can construct a chrome-extension:// URI for.  I have no idea if this will work better than the other attempts, but it seems like it should.

Comment: What is the purpose of your extension? Just passing raw data? Method 1 obviously results in an "invisible style sheet". It's similar to a content script. Method 2 fails, because the Same origin policy is in affect for `chrome-extension://...` resources on another page. Hence, `.cssRules` is `null`.

Comment: @RobW the thing that I don't understand about the cross domain policy is that the JavaScript that is trying to access a `chrome-extension://...` resource is actually script from the extension.  It seems like if the script is packaged with the extension, it should be able to access extension resources.  I'm realizing now that my expectation for cross-domain behavior is probably applicable to the background page's script, but not the content scripts.  I'm currently trying to implement [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720258/loading-an-asset-stored-within-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: The overall goal of accessing stylsheets this way is to pull a sheet from the packaged extension and inserting it into a WebKitShadowRoot element in order to implement a properly scoped UI component that is injected into the host page, but doesn't suffer from CSS pollution.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` cannot inject code at a `chrome-extension:` protocol. So, you're probably not using method #2 to inject the code at a page/tab within your extension. Since you're injecting the code at a page, which is not your extension, `.cssRules` is `null`. If this is not the case, update your question with a **small yet complete** test case to demonstrate your problem.