# Retrieve JSON stored locally Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing my first Chrome Extension.
I want to store a CSV file as a JSON, read the content and compare it with the URL.

Questions:

1. I'd normally store the CSV table in a database, but I don't have this option working with JavaScript. Do you see a better option in my case?
2. I have a `main.js` (content script) and a `script.js`.The content script calls the second one to read user's URL (it seems the content script cannot do it himself). After that I need to read the JSON file. In `script.js` I have

   ```
   load: function() {
       var list;
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           list = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
       }
       xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('resources/list.json'), true);
       xhr.send();
       return list;
   }
   ```

But it throws `"Cannot call method 'getURL' of undefined"`. I've tried to insert this `load()` function in `main.js`, store `list` using `localStorage` and then finally reading it inside `script.js`, but...nothing.. The information isn't stored. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an asset stored within a chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720258/loading-an-asset-stored-within-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1):

This is an [advertised limitation of Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). Your content scripts are living in a sandbox within a DOM page. Though injected by your extension, it's sharing almost nothing with it.

I recommend you to use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) if you need a single asynchronous request/response or to use [chrome.runtime.connect](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#connect) for repeated uses.

It helps you to rely on events within your own app, helping you decoupling your code.