# Debugging and Deploying Javascript: localhost vs production

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-deployment

I'm developing now a Chrome browser extension using Javascript.
While developing on my machine, I use localhost for debugging.

To be more specific, I have a symlink on my WWW local directory which points to a directory with a name like my site. e.g.:
`/users/html/www.mysite.com` is symlinked locally to `/users/dev/www.mysite.com`,

so when browsing to `http://localhost/mysite.com`, what's on `/users/dev/www.mysite.com` is served.

I also use iframe, so my code has an iframe tag with  `src=http://localhost/www.mysite.com/iframe/code.html` in it.

And to complicate matters, I also use `getJson` that supposed to get a URL, but it's a different URL for production and localhost.

I'm trying to find a way to easily debug locally and then seamlessly deploy to production, and that all paths will change to production, or more precisely, ask you how you go about with solving the deployment to production without messing with all the links, when I go back and forth from production to localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have two choices. Attempt them in this order...

1. Find a way to use [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). So you can just use `src="/iframe/code.html"`
2. Have a configuration file that you can change on each environment.

If you go down the configuration file route there's a useful question about how they can be used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720258/loading-an-asset-stored-within-a-chrome-extension).

Essentially have a `setting.json` file that contains the environment variable (production or development), and the urls to be used for each. Use `getJson` to load this file, and build your subsequent paths based on that.

Comment: Thank you Jivings for answering. How would you usually do the reading the setting.json file? do you have a lib you've written that you use with all your projects?

Comment: You can also store the boolean in local storage so you can switch environments on the fly without extra configuration files

Comment: Thanks @ZigMandel, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: I've found also this resource if anyone interested: https://npmjs.org/package/config.json

Comment: @leonid That's for `node.js` projects. You can load the settings file with the normal `getJson('settings.json');`. Just make sure the file is in the root of your project.

Comment: @leonid look at chrome.storage apis