# Chrome Extension / App Settings Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

So I'm trying to think of a method to get a "local" file not from the user but from the Google Chrome App or Extension which ever it may be since I am building both. Basically, it'll be my Settings JSON and I need access to it through my Options Page, like to have access to it via my content scripts but it's ok, and I need access to it via my Background page.

Sample Settings.json

```
{
    "defaultResults": "all",
    "view":"full",
    "results":"cur",
    "count":"5",
    "omni":{
        "h8":{
            "title":"Hello World",
            "url":"www.someurl.com"
        }
     }
}
```

So does anyone have any real options for this. I'm not positive if Google has already implemented a native function for this such as `chrome.getAppFile("file URL");` or something of that matter. I'd rather not use Ajax inside my app for this file. And I'd rather not use it everywhere. So hopefully, someone here will have a reasonable idea how I should go about this.

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3720372/3613282 Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks like a nice simple way to do it. I'll take a look at it. Can we edit the file using the FileSystem writer?

Comment: If you want to save the settings for future use, why not just use the chrome.storage API to store the JSON settings? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage For the FileSystem writer, I'm not sure if you can change a file which is `packed` with the extension. As long as I know, FileSystem writes to a `temporary sandboxed` zone.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought and currently I do use the storage API, I am later going to set up the sync for portability

Comment: Also, only apps are allowed to use the FileSystem API. For extensions, you will have to rely on the storage API.

Comment: Ah see I didn't know that part lol.

Comment: i haven't tested out the suggested answer yet. So if it works what should I do delete this one?

Comment: Just let this thread be. There may be other people searching for the same thing you were.

Comment: Alright sounds good to me thanks abhishek. If you are apart of the winter bash, you can answer this question and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720372/3613282) answer.

1. By assigning your JSON object to a variable, saving the script as `settings.js`, and including it in your background page, as follows:

`settings.js` looks as follows:

```
var settings =  {"param":value,...}; //Your JSON object
```

then, in your background page:

```
<script src="settings.js"></script>
```

2. By making an AJAX call to your `settings.json` from your background page:

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
   xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), true);
   xhr.send();
   ```

As discussed in the comments, you cannot use FileSystem API in chrome extensions. Only chrome apps have access to it. Either way, the FileSystem API works in a `sandboxed zone`, so I'm not sure if you can write to files `packed` with the extension.